# How to handle collision situation in socket.io?

Tags: android, websocket, socket.io

I am developing android application with socket.io. In this application I connect two user with each other. I have 3 screen, MainScreen, CategoryScreen, PictureScreen. In CategoryScreen I have nested recyclerView. Outer RecyclerView is vertical scrolling, Inner recyclerView horizontal scrolling. When one of user scroll the recycler view second user see scrolling of another user. Also if one of the user press back or choose category second user also should go back(previous screen) or open chosen category. How can I handle collision situation when two user scroll recycler view same time or navigate to other screen in app same time?

Comment: Those situations are called race conditions. You can either decide that one user has more prevalence for his actions (sort of 'moderator') based on whatever criteria that may have sense into your app. Or you let the race condition resolve itself : the server will process the two requests in a FIFO way : 'First In, First Out' ( using some sort of queue if you use multi-threaded or multi-node). Both will be confusing for your user, though. Race conditions results always are.

Comment: @Ariart thank you for your comment. I think have idea how to implement this task and I am not sure it is good solution. When one of the user have action I will block second user screen and back button action and server also will ignore second user action for 100-200ms.

Comment: It can be a solution. You just must see, by testing your UI, how it affect your user experiences. Another way to do it is to show to your users what the others are doign by visual indications, without forcing the UI to follow. For example, from user1 UI : user1 and user2 are on tab1 : you add user2 avatar, or username, in the tab1 label. When user2 move to tab2, you update the tab1 label, removing the use2 mark, and add it to the tab2, etc. You should learn from existing collaborative systems like GoogleDrive's one for example. Building UI/UX can be tricky, and they already solved problems.

Comment: @Ariart thank you. I will try to implement and test it.